# Get currentcell in CurrentCellChanged event silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have added CurrentCellChanged event in my application

this.dgMain.CurrentCellChanged += new EventHandler(dgMain_CurrentCellChanged);

event handler is as below
private void dgMain_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

Now in event handler how I will get current cell clicked.

Thanks in advance :):)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways but without knowing about your data, the only ones that come to mind is:

```
dgMain.CurrentColumn.GetCellContent
```

or

```
dgMain.SelectedItem
```